# Correct fingering for The Frail

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm learning to play E-Piano by myself and right now, I'm trying to play the The Frail. I don't have any problems in the first sixteen bars. But at bars 17 and 18 I'm struggling with the correct fingering. Can someone with more experience in playing the piano help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bar 17, on the *right hand* you can use :

- 4th finger on E
- 1st finger on G (thumb)
- 2nd finger on C
- 4th finger on E

and moving on to bar 18:

- 5th finger on F
- 2nd finger on C
- 1st finger on G

So basically, you can play these two bars without changing the position of your right hand at all.

For your *left hand* on bar 17 you can use 5th and 1st fingers for the octave and bar 18 you can use your 5th finger on low Eb and 2nd and 1st for the Eb (octave) and F.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. I always tried to press Eb and F simultaneously with my first finger on the right hand, which seemed to be wrong, as I didn't found a way to play Eb and F with my left hand. Hopefully, I can now play this composition.

Answer (score 2):

As with any piece you may have fingering difficulties, place your hand over all the notes you feel are within that span. Your thumb (r.h.) will look after the lowest note, and with a stretch such as this, which is less than an octave, your pinky could play the highest note. Then look at where your other fingers arre in comparison to the notes needed.

I'm not prescribibg what fingers you use - hat's up to you, and part of the practice of playing something new. But I'm sure you will work out the best fingering (your fingering) for this, and any other piece. Moving laterally when you can already reach most/all the keys isn't a good move.

On bar 20 or 21, looking ahead, you can see there's no note lower than C, so your whole hand can be moved up, using the same span idea, putting your pinky, if you like, on the top B♭. Pinky or ring finger - it's a black key, so ring may reach more easily.

Comment: Many thanks for this generic advice. I'll try to incorporate it into my daily exercises.